# Convert row SQL query to Laravel Eloquent Query

Tags: php, mysql, eloquent, eloquent-relationship, laravel-relations

I need this query to be Laravel eloquent, and also, how can I join the above tables in one single eloquent relational query?
I have tried many examples to solve this query if any ideas on how to solve this please describe me in response.[enter link description here](https://prnt.sc/f3DIykNjJMf1)

Comment: Please do not include images of code! You previously included the query as text in your question. Why did you change it to an image of the query? You can improve the efficiency of this query by dropping the unnecessary joins to `courses` and `lessons` tables in the derived table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here was the source code which builds on its own with some assumptions. Because it was difficult to assume all related tables and it's content.

php artisan make:model Course

```html
class Course extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'courses';

    public function subscriptions()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Subscription::class);
    }

    public function lessons()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Lesson::class);
    }
}
```

Update User Model

```html
class User extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'users';

    public function client()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Client::class);
    }

    public function lessons()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Lesson::class)->withPivot('result');
    }
}
```

php artisan make:model Subscription

```html
class Subscription extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'subscriptions';

    public function client()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Client::class);
    }

    public function courses()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Course::class);
    }
}
```

```html
class Client extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'clients';

    public function subscriptions()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Subscription::class);
    }

    public function users()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(User::class);
    }
}
```

php artisan make:model Client

```html
class Lesson extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'lessons';

    public function courses()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Course::class);
    }

    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class)->withPivot('result');
    }
}
```

web.php

```html
Route::get('/view-course/{client_id}', ['as' => 'course.view', 'uses' => 'CourseController@viewCourseByClient']);
```

Here is the final Query which you write in CourseController controller.

```html
public function viewCourseByClient($client_id){
  $completed_courses = Course::select('courses.name as course_name', 'courses.description as course_description')
    ->addSelect(DB::raw('SUM(course_completed) as user_completed_count'))
    ->addSelect(DB::raw('COUNT(DISTINCT tmp.user_id) as total_user_count'))
    ->join('subscription_courses', 'courses.id', '=', 'subscription_courses.course_id')
    ->join('subscriptions', 'subscription_courses.subscription_id', '=', 'subscriptions.id')
    ->join('clients', 'subscriptions.client_id', '=', 'clients.id')
    ->join('users', 'clients.id', '=', 'users.client_id')
    ->join('course_lessons', 'courses.id', '=', 'course_lessons.course_id')
    ->join('lessons', 'course_lessons.lesson_id', '=', 'lessons.id')
    ->leftJoin('user_lessons', function ($join) use ($client_id) {
        $join->on('lessons.id', '=', 'user_lessons.lesson_id')
            ->on('users.id', '=', 'user_lessons.user_id')
            ->where('user_lessons.result', '=', 'completed')
            ->where('clients.id', '=', $client_id);
    })
    ->groupBy('courses.id', 'users.id')
    ->selectSub(function ($query) {
        $query->selectRaw('CASE WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN user_lessons.result = \'completed\' THEN course_lessons.lesson_id END) = COUNT(DISTINCT course_lessons.lesson_id) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as course_completed')
            ->from('courses')
            ->join('subscription_courses', 'courses.id', '=', 'subscription_courses.course_id')
            ->join('subscriptions', 'subscription_courses.subscription_id', '=', 'subscriptions.id')
            ->join('clients', 'subscriptions.client_id', '=', 'clients.id')
            ->join('users', 'clients.id', '=', 'users.client_id');

  return view('course.completed_courses', compact($completed_courses));
}
```

Hope this will help you.